# Create a Win32 Console Client with C# to Access remote DCOM Server, got the error 80070005

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dcom

My OS is Win7 Ultimate Chinese edition, tool is VS2010 Ultimate. I created a DCOM Serve with VS2010 following below steps: Visual C++ -> atl -> exe -> add a interface, and compiled it with no error.

Then copy the idl file to another directory, using "MIDL xxx.idl" command to compile the idl file, got the tlb file, and using "tlbimp xxxlib.tlb" to get the xxxlib.dll file. After that, I created a win32 console exe application with C# referecing the xxxlib.dll.

The question is when I run the C# client, I got the error 80070005, saying got the remote componant with CLSID {xxx} failed.

Ps: I'm sure the connection between two machine has no question because I can ping each other. I also registered the xxxps.dll on the server machine.

Comment: You have to adjust DCOM settings. Google for something like *DCOM Configuration Tutorial*. For example - http://j2eeps.cern.ch/wikis/download/attachments/23334221/DCOM_Config_Step_by_Step.pdf

Comment: @SChepurin Thank u very much, Schepurin. But I Can't find my DCOM component under the "DCOM configuration" subtree in the "component service" window. Please give me more tips, Thanks.

Comment: You should register the server using *regsvr32* utility -http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx

Comment: Access denied errors are definitely what killed DCOM and gave Java a major leg up.  Just pinging the machine doesn't prove anything, the user account that the client program uses must be known on the server machine as well and have sufficient rights on that machine.  Having to impersonate another user gets ugly very quickly and DCOM config or CoInitializeSecurity is a black hole.

Comment: @SChepurin : Thank u for your tips, but I had already 'regsvr32' the server.

Comment: @HansPassant : Thank u 4 your comments. I think I will give it up. But before that could you help to confirm whether it's right for my client codes: <br/>
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Guid guid = new Guid("B69467A5-0118-40D4-B25B-FA68B2E2A422");
            System.Type t = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid, "192.168.10.100", true);
            object COMobject = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            PowerSwitch myclass = (PowerSwitch)COMobject;
            myclass.setEquipmentPw("four", 1);
        }
    }
}